# postfix error fatal:table lookup

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, postfix

here the mail.log

```
server localhost: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld
/mysqld.sock' (2)
    Mar 23 23:07:19 ubuntu postfix/trivial-rewrite[6417]: fatal: mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf(0,lock|fold_fix): table lookup problem
    Mar 23 23:07:20 ubuntu postfix/smtpd[6401]: warning: problem talking to service rewrite: Success
    Mar 23 23:07:20 ubuntu postfix/cleanup[6296]: warning: problem talking to service rewrite: Connection reset by peer
    Mar 23 23:07:20 ubuntu postfix/master[6291]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/trivial-rewrite pid 6417 exit status 1
    Mar 23 23:07:20 ubuntu postfix/master[6291]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/trivial-rewrite: bad command startup -- throttling
```

netstat -l|grep mysql

```
tcp        0      0 localhost:mysql         *:*                     LISTEN     
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10671    /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

and i can connect through this

```
mysql -u postfix -h 127.0.0.1 -p postfix
```

Comment: Was it ever working before? If so what changed since? What have you tried so far to fix it?

Comment: no i couldnt make it work

Comment: Then ask a local consultant/administrator.

Answer (score 5):

Start your local MySQL server.

Comment: thanx for reply but can u explain more

Comment: No. You didn't explain either.

Comment: Run `sudo /sbin/service mysqld start` and tell us what it says...

Comment: root@ubuntu:~# sudo /sbin/service mysqld start
   sudo: /sbin/service: command not found

Comment: Run `sudo /usr/sbin/service mysqld start` and tell us what it says.

Comment: this is what i get
sudo: /sbin/service: command not found 
and if this command to run mysql .... mysql is running

Answer (score 2):

MySQL usually has two ways to connect to it: the Unix socket and an IP address.

In the error message above, Postfix is using the socket and your testing is using the IP address.

Check that the socket exists and is where Postfix thinks it is (`/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`).

Also check that the username and password that Postfix is using work for you through the socket.  MySQL permissions care about username, password **and** the source of the connection.  Just because you can connect from one IP address doesn't mean you can from another.  This means that with the same username, you can have a different password and permissions if you connect from a different place.  This also includes connecting via the Unix socket.  Make sure your testing is done the same way Postfix connects.

Answer (score 0):

what is your os version and mysql version? depending on what they are, you can use something like /etc/init.d/mysql (could be mysqld in some versions) status to find out if it is running in ubuntu.

then you can use locate mysqld.sock to find out if the socket file is actually in the location postfix user is trying to use.

Comment: im working on Ubuntu 11.10 and mysql is 5.1